# Keep Refraction and Remove the background object

Tags: shaders, transparency, glass

Hope you're all good,

I have a question, I made an object and use the refraction BSDF on it, so it refract the image I put in the background. And I want to keep the refraction of the object but i want to make transparent the background. If you can help me and know how to do this, please tell me :) 
I put you the picture i work on. The first picture is with the background. And the second picture is what i want to acvhieve but with the refraction of the first picture.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods you could use to achieve this.

The most practical ones are:

1. Material with a light path node
2. Compositing

for a simple scene like yours, I'd recommend the material option as you just need to add 3 nodes to your material setup and you can see the result in the viewport.

In my case the sphere is the refractive object, and the cube is the background object.

Add a `mix shader` between your existing shader and the material output node (in the background object material that is).
add a `light path node` -> `is transmission ray` to the `fac` input of the `mix shader node`.

add a `transparent shader` with a white color in the first (white emission shader in the screenshot) and your existing shader in the second shader slot (red emission shader in the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: thank's a lot !!